# How to configure application window properties at launch

Tags: windows

Windows-10: When starting IE, firefox or the file manager: how can the default windows properties be configured?  Specifically:

- width / height of window
- location of upper-left corner

It would be nice to be able to not have to configure the size of these windows each time and create a custom panel of applications: each app with a designated size / location

Comment: Most applications actually open up at the same place you closed it. If you open up windows explorer, move it around a bit, then close it and open it again you will see that it saved your last location.

Comment: After googling around a bit I actually found a superuser question like yours, it is however Windows Vista - http://superuser.com/questions/246402/default-window-size-and-positions